# Give specific user permission to write to a folder using +w notation

Tags: permissions

I know I can assign the permission to write to an owner/group/others like this:

```
chmod u+w myfolder
```

Can I specify the specific user here? Some like this:

```
chmod username u+w myfolder
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why don't you just add the user to the group?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

If you want to change the user owning this file or directory (folder), you will have to use the command `chown`. For instance, if you run

```
sudo chown username: myfolder
```

the user owning myfolder will be username. Then you can execute

```
sudo chmod u+w myfolder
```

to add the write permission to the username user.

But if you want to add this user to the group associated with "myfolder", you can run

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupname username
```

and then execute

```
sudo chmod g+w myfolder
```

to add the write permission to the group.

Comment: There is a way in which both users will have access to the folder, and a group is not needed; it was suggested in an answer for the same question here: superuser.com/a/235398/191720.

Comment: Can I do this without `sudo`?

Comment: @becko: You can if you drop to a root shell.

Comment: @Charo I meant without root

Comment: @becko: You must have root privileges to change permissions associated to users or groups.

Comment: +1 for `chmod g+w myfolder` . That's what I've been missing.

Comment: Why is there a colon after username?

Comment: @AER: In the first command, if a colon follows `username` the owning group is also changed to `username` (if you omit such a colon, the owning group will not change).

Comment: You can add the -R for recursive option. For more options type chown --help

Comment: Could you expand on "groupname" is a group name supposed to already exist? How do we see it? How do we see who is in it? Or should I create it? Can I add someone to the group just for one directory or will this affect all other permissions related to this group?

Answer (score 423):

You could use `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -m u:username:rwx myfolder
```

This sets permissions for specific users, without changing the ownership of the directory.

Check out the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/setfacl.1) for further details and examples.

**Note:**

- `setfacl` is short for *set File ACL* (Access Control List)
- If you want to apply it recursively to all the subdirectories: add the **-R** flag like this:

  ```
  setfacl -R -m u:username:rwx myfolder
  ```

Comment: Perfect answer! Also `setfacl` is available on CentOS (`yum -y install acl`) & FreeBSD as well.

Comment: just a note: setfacl = set File ACL, ACL = Access Control List hence for short "setFacl" - easier way to remember i think.

Comment: If you want to apply it recursively to all the subdirectories: add the -R flag like this: `setfacl -R -m u:username:rwx myfolder`

Comment: easiest way to give permission for a new user

Comment: Is there a way to grant a user `rw` without changing any existing `x` permission, if operating on multiple files or recursively?

Comment: Sure, just leave the `x` out in the command above.

Comment: This is much safer than 'chown' and 'chmod' commands that can easily break a server if you're still learning the ropes on Linux distros.

Comment: @DrG that does in fact unset the x flag! I tried it and lost access to the directory and all subdirs which apparently require the x flag in order to access them.

Comment: Will this work for newly created files as well, or do we need to re-apply permissions each time new files are created?

Comment: I get `Operation not supported`

Comment: if you get a "Operation not supported" this means its most likely an external mount that is not mounted with acl support. in the fstab add the acl option and remount it

Answer (score 16):

No this is not possible. You can either change the owner of the file with

```
[sudo] chown username: foldername
```

or you can add the user to the group that owns the file with

```
usermod -a -G {group-name} username
```

Comment: `useradd -G {group-name} username` tells me that username already exists

Comment: i tried this but my user still can't write to that folder

Answer (score 11):

If you want to apply it recursively to all the subdirectories: add the -R flag like this:

```
setfacl -R -m u:username:rwx myfolder
```

Comment: This does not work for multiple drives.

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu recursively (folder and it's all sub folders) giving permission to a specific user:

```
sudo chown -R <username>: <folderName>
```