# Cannot create file in /var/www/html

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php

I am running Ubuntu version 14.04, and I have an apache2 server set up to host some php files on localhost that are stored in `/var/www/html`.

When I try to execute the following code in one of my php script

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
fwrite($file,"Hello World. Testing!");
fclose($file);
?>
```

I do not find a file stored in my /var/www/html named test.txt, or anywhere on my computer after searching. The file name does not already exist, and I am using `sudo nautilus` because I do not have the necessary permissions to edit the php files inside the `/var/www/html`. Why are the files not appearing in my `/var/www/html` folder and how can I fix this so that the file is created?

Comment: User `www-data` having write access to the `www` directory (or one of its subfolders) is a major security hazard on production, and bad practice in general. Please pick a separate data folder, or use a database engine instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tested your php file in my server and it works just fine.

You problem must be that the user `www-data` doesn't have write permissions to that folder.

If indeed that user doesn't have write permissions to that folder, then you will see error messages at the file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

In order to look at the last errors, do

```
tail -n 15 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

For example, if I, instead of "test.txt", put "/test.txt" (write to /, were only root can) I get this error inside the log file:

```
[:error] [pid 7505] [client 127.0.0.1:47066] PHP Warning:  fopen(/test.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/a.php on line 2
```

The above clearly states that permission is denied.

You can fix this problem by giving write permission to that folder for user `www-data`.

[give specific user permission to write to a folder using +w notation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation)

Comment: I appreciate your effort to help, but when I gave the file permissions it did not work. I also did not find the line you gave in my error log.

Comment: Can you please go from your browser to the `php` page you posted and then edit your post with the contents of the `error.log` file?

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. It was in the error log, I was just searching the wrong one. Thank you.