# add user as another person with write permission on a folder

Tags: permissions

I'd like to ADD myself (already in the webapps group) with `drwxrwxrwx` permission to the whole folder recursively:

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
total 67904
drwxrwxrwx 3 root    webapps     4096 Oct  1 21:39 ROOT
drwxrwxrwx 8 tomcat8 tomcat8     4096 Oct 11 18:01 AppWeb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat8 tomcat8 69522664 Oct 11 18:01 AppWeb.war
```

I don't want to remove permissions from users that already have it.

Other posts either come close to helping me or I don't understand, because I'm new.

It may help to know:

```
$ getent group webapps
webapps:x:1002:tony,root,tomcat8
```

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/809562/158442

Comment: now running the command shows this
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ROOT
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? AppWeb
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? AppWeb.war

Comment: Now, I have to run SUDO ls -l /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps just to see the original permissions because "Permission denied" for me

Comment: I typed 
setfacl -m u:tony:rw /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
Didn't I do it right?
Anybody? Bueller?
Thanks.

Comment: Ouch. That should have been `setfacl -m u:tony:rwx /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps`. I'll correct that answer now.

Comment: Okay, using sudo, I'm back where I began. :) that's good. :) I'm still not listed when running the ls -l command. :\

Comment: `ls` won't show ACL attributes (try `getfacl` instead)

Comment: OMG, thank you! thanks for your time, thanks for helping me. :)