# How to use chmod to give a single user from my group permission to my directory?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

so ubuntu noob here but I'm in a group with different people having different usernames. So I made a directory, and I want to share this with a single user from that group. How do I achieve this? I want to give rwx access.

Thank you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [give specific user permission to write to a folder using +w notation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487527/give-specific-user-permission-to-write-to-a-folder-using-w-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setfacl`

```
setfacl -m u:username:rwx myfolder
```

This sets permissions for specific users, without changing the ownership of the directory.

Comment: thanks! I actually tried it but I got the error setfacl: folder_name operation not supported. Unfortunately I don't have root access so I can't try apt-get. Could you please suggest what to do?

Comment: @ai_boy check this one https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/402415/255251