# Changing folder ownership/permission has no effect

Tags: 18.04, azure

I'm using an ubuntu VM machine on Azure. The goal is to allow `user1` to to upload files to `/folder1/folder2` through a `scp` command. Right now I get `Permission denied`.

I run the commands directly on the VM in azure. `whoami` results in `root`.

I have run

- `sudo chown user1 /folder1/folder2` to [change ownership](https://linuxhint.com/change-directory-owner-linux/).
- `setfacl -m u:user1:rwx /folder1/folder2` to [give user1 permission](https://askubuntu.com/a/809562/1656305).

But when I run

- `ls -l /folder1/folder2` to view permissions, nothing has changed and `user1` still doesn't have permission to transfer the file.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The commands all seem to be successful when running them as `root`.

Comment: What is the filesystem on which /folder1/folder2 resides? How is it mounted? Use `findmnt -T /folder1/folder2` if you're not sure

Comment: @steeldriver This is what I get:

TARGET /folder1/folder2 .... SOURCE /dev/mapper/{GUID} ... FSTYPE ext4 ....  OPTIONS rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime... Not sure what to make of this.

Comment: @steeldriver I got it to work when adding the -R option, i.e. `sudo chown -R user1 /folder1/folder2`. To my understanding that means I gave user1 ownership of all subfolders. I don't see why that helped. Does it make sense to you?